# ArcObjects Maplex labeling doesn't work?

Tags: arcmap, arcobjects, maplex

I am trying to modify a FeatureLayer's Maplex label settings. For some reason those properties don't get modified when opening the document afterwards. 
The document I am opening HAS already set the option "Use maplex label engine" property set.

```
def ApplyModificationsMainLayer(featureLayer):
    featureLayer.Name = "PAD"
    pGeoFeatureLayer = CType(featureLayer, esriCarto.IGeoFeatureLayer)
    pGeoFeatureLayer.DisplayAnnotation = True
    propertiesCollection = pGeoFeatureLayer.AnnotationProperties

    pLabelEngineLayerProperties = NewObj(esriCarto.MaplexLabelEngineLayerProperties, esriCarto.ILabelEngineLayerProperties2)

    pMaplexOverposter = NewObj(esriCarto.MaplexOverposterLayerProperties, esriCarto.IMaplexOverposterLayerProperties)
    pMaplexOverposter.FeatureType = 1
    pMaplexOverposter.LinePlacementMethod = 7
    pMaplexOverposter.PrimaryOffset = 10
    pMaplexOverposter.PrimaryOffsetUnit = 0
    pMaplexOverposter.CanReduceFontSize = True
    pOverposter = CType(pMaplexOverposter, esriCarto.IOverposterLayerProperties)
    pLabelEngineLayerProperties.OverposterLayerProperties = pOverposter

    pLabelEngineLayerProperties.Expression = "[Length]"
    pLabelEngineLayerProperties.Symbol.Size = 7




    propertiesCollection.Clear()
    propertiesCollection.Add(pLabelEngineLayerProperties)
    #cast to ILayer before saving
    pLayer = CType(pGeoFeatureLayer, esriCarto.ILayer)
    return pLayer
```

I have tried to get a reference of the "Default" Label Class and it seems that when I try to cast it's OverposterLayerProperties to IMaplexOverposterLayerProperties it returns a Null Type Pointer.

Why would this happen ?

Comment: Are you saving your MXD? Is this ArcObjects in python? Can you try this in an active ArcMap session and see if the settings are being applied there?

Comment: Yes, this is ArcObjects in Python. I do have a template.mxd which I am saving with MapDocument.SaveAs() function. I have already opened the "saved" document and it also has the "Use Maplex Label Engine" set also.

Comment: The only thing I can see at a glance is that IGeoFeatureLayer doesn't implement ILayer, try pLayer = CType(featurelayer, esriCarto.ILayer), the properties should already be updated on the IFeatureLayer.

Comment: It doesn't work either. By the way this code used to work perfectly when I was using Standard Label Engine

Comment: I have tried to get a reference of the "Default" Label Class and it seems that when I try to cast it's OverposterLayerProperties to IMaplexOverposterLayerProperties it returns a Null Type Pointer. Why would this happen ?

Comment: If this is ArcObjects in Python then a code snippet that illustrates what you have tried and where you are stuck should also include some Python.  If Python is irrelevant to your question then there is no need to mention it so that potential answerers can focus on providing ArcObjects answers.